# Use webdeploy from VS2010 to publish a MySql database

Tags: mysql, visual-studio-2010, web-deployment

I'm using the WebDeploy tool from Visual Studio 2010 since a few weeks and really like it. I was now trying to deploy my database as well using the 'Package/Publish SQL' tab. However, my current project uses a MySQL database and it seems that web deploy from VS is only compatible using MSSQL (sigh).

So my question is: can I get it to deploy my MySQL database? I know there is a custom 'dbFullMySql' provider, but not sure if this can integrate into VS2010. Thanks.

Comment: I have the same problem. Have you found a way to solve this?

Comment: After those years....Did you find the solution now?

Comment: No but I haven't used it since to be honest. Quite sure something similar is possible nowadays though. There is a Entity Framework MySql provider and I'm quite sure you can make the publishing pretty seamless when using Azure at least.

Answer (score 0):

could this be of help to you http://blogs.iis.net/msdeploy/archive/2009/04/29/changes-to-the-custom-provider-for-mysql-dbfullmysql.aspx

Comment: No, I've already seen that link. That uses the command line tool. I want to deploy from within VS 2010. How I can use the custom provider they mention in the article, *that* is the real question...

Comment: hmmm i would find for the sake of sanity and less errors etc that it may be wise to just use something like navicat rather than trying to get microsoft to play ball with MySQL  whats more Mysql or really quite lame when it comes to keeping up with the needs of its clients with regards to tools like this and have always been quite a bit behind, i think if you did find a solution you may start getting problems with data types etc and in the long run maybe create more work when you simply really only need to import a SQL file :-)